# Zend_Mail - how to get only html body from email?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm working with emails from google oauth.  This is the format I'm using.

$emailmessage = $storage->getMessage($i);
$fromaddress = $storage->getMessage($i)->from;

What format can I use to get only the html body of the email?

I've been looking at this document http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail.html, but the formatting seems off.  It only has getFrom, which leads me to believe it's an old version.

**EDIT: I'm using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` will not return `Zend_Mail` but `Zend_Mail_Message`. So, you'll have to look here for the functions: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail_Message.html. As you can see it extends `Zend_Mail_Part` which has the `getContent()` method.

The way to get the body part is (in one line):

```
$content = $storage->getMessage($i)->getContent();
```

Comment: $storage->getBodyHtml($i);  ?

Comment: I guess `$storage->getMessage($i)` returns an instant of `Zend_Mail`? So it is `$storage->getMessage($i)->getBodyHtml()`

Comment: : Call to undefined method Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::getBodyHtml() in  - trying the second one now

Comment: Using method 2 - $storage->getMessage($i)->getBodyHtml() causes : Call to undefined method Zend_Mail_Message::getBodyHtml() in

Comment: It would have been better to tell before that you're using `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` ;)

Comment: Sorry - first time using zend - so I really have no idea

Comment: No problem, as long as you are descriptive. ;)

Comment: Does getContent show only the html?  I'll need to parse this after and get the contents between the two html body tags.

Comment: Have a look at preg_match for that. php.net/preg_match, and here: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html